# Mock document.querySelectorAll() in angular test Case

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, fullcalendar, karma-jasmine

I have following code in my method, which removes particular class from the fullcalendar events and do someother things after that.

```
 someMethod() {
   let events = document.querySelectorAll(`.calendar-event`);
   events.forEach((event) => {
     event.classList.remove('calendar-read-event');
   });
   //dosomething
  }
```

When running the test cases due to some reason the fullcalendar is not displayed and when i call this method i am getting error

> 'Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined'

This is because calendar-event class is not loaded yet and i am getting no result for querySelectorAll() , Is there a way to spyon document.querySelectorAll() and return some value.

Something like this in beforeEach method:

```
spyOn(document, 'querySelectorAll').and.returnValue(NodeList);
```

Have tried this but its not stubbing the value and I am still getting 'Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined' error

Comment: I think if you find yourself having "querySelectorAll" or any other direct DOM selection API in your angular app there is something missing. There are better ways to do this in Angular

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the `document` directly, Angular has a token (`DOCUMENT` in `@angular/common`) to inject the document using DI.

```js
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

@Component({...}) // could be a service too!
export class MyComponent {
  constructor (@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {}

  // Reference this.document instead of document.
  someMethod() {
    let events = this.document.querySelectorAll(`.calendar-event`);
    events.forEach((event) => {
      event.classList.remove('calendar-read-event');
    });
  }
}
```

Then in your test you can mock the document and provide it as a dependency.  This way your test and the component will reference the same document instance.

```js
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  const mockDocument = jasmine.createSpyObject('Document', ['querySelectorAll'])

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      // Your other stuff here
      providers: [{ provide: DOCUMENT, useValue: mockDocument }]
    });
  });
```

Note: The above code is untested and may not be 100% correct.  It's meant to give you an idea as to how to approach the issue.

> https://medium.com/ngconf/how-to-inject-document-in-angular-7d17804430b6

Comment: Ya , will try this out . Thanks for the feedback.